# How to disable inline edit in list view?

Tags: list-view, inline, disable

Please refer to the following screen capture:

[image: screen]

I would like to disable editing in list view for all users. However, I can't seem to find a resource for Salesforce Lightning. Can anyone instruct me on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many permission which you can turned off for your user to enable the inline editing for your users.

- Enable Inline Editing' and 'Enable Enhanced Lists' preferences is required. (under Setup | Customize | User Interface).
- The 'Mass Edit from Lists' permission.

Answer (score 0):

> One quick work-around is, to add a default record type.

If you add record type then you need to filter the list by record type for inline edit. If you don't filter the list view with record type, then you automatically Salesforce disables the list view inline edit.