# Disable Inline Editing for fields in the list view in lightning

Tags: lightning, inline

I am trying to figure out to disable the inline edit in the list view but not able to do so. There are already [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214194/how-to-disable-inline-edit-in-list-view) related to this but that does not helped me.

I have disabled these check boxes from org:-

[image]

but could not **The Mass Edit from Lists permission** under system permission.

[image]

Comment: Mass edit from Lists is present under General User Permissions

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper General User Permissions is a section  under the old interface of profile editor in Salesforce. I have enabled the enhanced profile editor and it has been changed to system permission.

Answer (score 0):

> One quick work-around is, to add a default record type.

If you add record type then you need to filter the list by record type for inline edit. If you don't filter the list view with record type, then you automatically Salesforce disables the list view inline edit.